# SQL: How to get date range counts as rows instead of columns?

Tags: sql

The generalized use case I have is to get record counts for a number of date ranges across one or more tables.

My specific use case is this:
For a patient encounter table (enc) and a pregnancy table (preg), get the counts of patients seen 9 months before the expected due date, 12 months before, 15 months before, etc.

I can get the data I need by doing an outer join on the encounter table with a where clause that boxes the time constraints.  However, this seems to be inefficient, a lot of typing, and the data are not in the form I'd like (I would like each time window to be a row instead of a column).

Below is the query I currently have.  How can I rewrite it to get the data row wise instead of column wise?

```
select 
  preg.org, 
  count(distinct nine.patient_id) `Pre-Delivery Visits (09 Months)`,
  count(distinct twelve.patient_id) `Pre-Delivery Visits (12 Months)`,
  count(distinct all.patient_id) `Pre-Delivery Visits (All)`,
  count(distinct preg.patient_id) `All Pregnancies`
from 
  pregnancy preg
  left outer join enc nine on preg.patient_id = nine.patient_id and nine.encounter_date < preg.est_delivery_date and nine.encounter_date > date_add(preg.est_delivery_date, (-30*9))
  left outer join enc twelve on preg.patient_id = twelve.patient_id and twelve.encounter_date < preg.est_delivery_date and twelve.encounter_date > date_add(preg.est_delivery_date, (-30*12))
  left outer join enc all on preg.patient_id = all.patient_id and all.encounter_date < preg.est_delivery_date
group by 1
;
```

Data are returned in this format:

```
org    (09 Months)  (12 months)  (All)  (All Pregnancies)
org x  1            10           15     20            
org y  2            22           23     24
org z  200          202          230    250
```

I'd like to get the data like this

```
org    time_box  count
org x  09 mon    1
org y  09 mon    2
org z  09 mon    202
org x  12 mon    10
...
etc.
```

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this does what you want.  This calculates non-overlapping groups, so 12 months is really 9-12 months:

```
select (case when e.encounter_date > p.est_delivery_date - 30*9 day
             then 'nine'
             when e.encounter_date > p.est_delivery_date - 30*12 day
             then 'twelve'
             when e.encounter_date is not null
             then 'all pre-delivery'
             else 'all pregnancy'
        end) as grp,
       count(distinct p.patient_id)            
from pregnancy p left join
     enc e
     on e.patient_id = p.patient_id and
        e.encounter_date < p.est_delivery_date 
group by grp;
```

Comment: Looks like it should work.  I'll give it a try in the morning!